# Methods in other classes c#

Tags: c#, forms, class, methods

What am I missing?
Method in form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form  
{  
    ...  
    public void DoSomething()  
      {  
            <Database call to update a list on Form1>  
      }  
      ...  
}
```

From a User Control:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl  
{  
      ...  
      private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
      {  
            Form1.DoSomething();  
      }  
      ...  
}
```

I am unable to access the method. I tried using "`Form1 frm = new Form1()`" and
when i attempt to use `frm.DoSomthing()` it exist but doesnt actually update the
list, i know the update code works and I know there is data becaue i tested. I
think my problem with this is that the "NEW" keyword is making a different
object and not updating the original object.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What you're doing here is not something you _should_ be doing.

Comment: update a listview on form1.

Comment: you are mixing up classes and objects ... Form1 is a class ... if you instanciate it, you get an object ... you can instanciate it multiple times ... the question now is: how should the system know which of the multiple objects you mean?

Comment: @MjM: *Which* instance of `Form1`? Do you have a reference to it?

Comment: I do not have a reference to it, not sure how other than creating a new instance...

Comment: You could use parent to get the control above it until you find the form but I must agree with Austin this is not a good idea.  You would be better off creating an event for your form to catch then directly accessing the form from the usercontrol.  But something like this would get you what you want if the usercontrol is a direct decendant of the form
Form1 test = (this.Parent as Form1);
test.doSomething();

Comment: From a conceptual point of view, why should a user control loading load a list view somewhere else?  I just fail to see why that work flow should ever exist.

Answer (score 2):

The UserControl shouldn't be able to access methods on Form1.  What you may want to do is have an event that fires on your UserControl that Form1  is listening to and updates the list.  Without knowing more of your architecture and what is actually going on it's difficult to give you more specific advise.

Comment: ok, let me look into that. what is it that would be blocking a UC from accessing public methods on Form1? is it something to do with it being a partial class?

Comment: So your code above can't access methods on Form1 because you need an instance of a class in order to access non-static methods of that class.  **However** you should **never** do what your code above does.  I would suggest looking into MVC or MVVM and Separation of Concerns.  Your UI pattern (MVC or MVVM) is often determined based on what type of application you are developing.

Comment: thank you for your advice... its all new to me when I start, i learn somthing and sometimes depending on what I learned start over... but i love it, love to create and love the challenge. Thanks everyone for your input.